# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is adding new records instead of UPDATE existing ones

Tags: php, mysql

I searched on stack and try to apply many solutions i found, but not a single is working with this one.

I have a problem with this query because ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is INSERT new results instead of updating existing ones.

```
INSERT INTO signal_providers_relations (
    id,
    client_id, 
    provider_id, 
    active_sp, 
    subscription_sp, 
    created_by, 
    cr_datetime, 
    ea_settings_active_sp, 
    ea_settings_sp,
    up_datetime, 
    sp_risk_allocation, 
    sp_max_trades ) 
VALUES (
    '',
    '".$user_id."', 
    '".$r['provider_id']."', 
    '".$r['active_sp']."', 
    '".$r['subscription_sp']."', 
    '".$r['created_by']."', 
    '".$r['cr_datetime']."', 
    '".$r['ea_settings_active_sp']."', 
    '".$r['ea_settings_sp']."', 
    '".$r['up_datetime']."', 
    '".$r['sp_risk_allocation']."', 
    '".$r['sp_max_trades']."'
    )
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE 
    id = '".$r['id']."'
    client_id = '".$user_id."', 
    provider_id = '".$r['provider_id']."', 
    active_sp = '".$r['active_sp']."', 
    subscription_sp = '".$r['subscription_sp']."', 
    created_by = '".$r['created_by']."', 
    cr_datetime = '".$r['cr_datetime']."', 
    ea_settings_active_sp = '".$r['ea_settings_active_sp']."', 
    ea_settings_sp = '".$r['ea_settings_sp']."', 
    up_datetime = '".$r['up_datetime']."', 
    sp_risk_allocation = '".$r['sp_risk_allocation']."', 
    sp_max_trades = '".$r['sp_max_trades']."'
```

Here is a image with table structure

[image]

Comment: On which column(s) do you have a unique index?  Keep in mind, if you don't tell MySQL which columns need to be treated as unique, then `ON DUPLICATE KEY` won't work/do anything.

Comment: Looking at those images, the **only** `UNIQUE` key you have in your table is the `PRIMARY` key on `id` ... which you're not setting - it *looks* like you should have a `UNIQUE` compound key on `client_id` and `provider_id`

Comment: @CD001 even if i use id in query its still insert new records

Comment: Specifying an existing id in the query?

Comment: @CD001 Yes, that's why i told in my question that i didn't find a solution for this

Comment: Could you update the question then, with the id update the query? From what you've got here currently, I'd expect new records to be inserted...

Comment: You're inserting an empty string into `id` in that query ... so, there won't *be* a `DUPLICATE` key - so `ON DUPLICATE KEY` won't trigger.

Comment: @CD001 thanks how i see where is a problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this table holds data specific to a single client/provider relationship then your `UNIQUE` identifier is *really* a combination of the `client_id` and `provider_id` - so you could drop your current `client_id` and `provider_id` `INDEXES` and replace them with a `UNIQUE` compound index.

```
ALTER TABLE `signal_providers_relations` DROP INDEX `client_id`;
ALTER TABLE `signal_providers_relations` DROP INDEX `provider_id`;

ALTER TABLE `test`.`signal_providers_relations` 
    ADD UNIQUE `unique_client_provider` (`client_id`, `provider_id`);
```

This will give you a specific, unique key which *would* trigger `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` when you attempt to insert data for a specific client/provider combination that already exists, which is what I think you're trying to achieve.

It's quite likely you could, at this point, drop the meaningless `id` column and change that `unique_client_provider` key just created to being the `PRIMARY` instead - but that may have repercussions on other parts of your code.

Answer (score -1):

to avoid this use REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO in your query